# Redux store get empty in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware, redux-async-actions

I have a problem with getting the redux store in my component. I am using redux-react async to fetch data from api. I got the data from jsonplaceholder api, however I have a problem configuring the store and connecting the store with the root component. I can see there is data in the store using a logger and the redux developments tools extension.

I did  `console.log(store.getState())` in the index component and the store is empty: `clientData: {}`. I have no idea what I have missed, I need some tips.

//action creator

```
export const datafeachsuccess = data => {
    return {
      type: FEACH_SUCCESS,
      data: data
    };
  } 

export const getClientData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            }).then(json => {
                dispatch(datafeachsuccess(json))
            })
          }}
```

// client data reducer

```
const clientReducer =(state = {}, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
      case FEACH_DATA:
        return {
          ...state,
          requestData: 'requesting Data'
        };
      case FEACH_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          client: action.data
        };
      case FEACH_FAILD:
        return {
          ...state,
          error: action.data
        }
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
export default  clientReducer;
```

//rootreducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import clientReducer from './clientreducer/clientreducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    clienetData: clientReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

//configuring store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './../reducer/rootReducer'
import thunkMiddelware from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

export default function configureStore() {
   return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddelware, loggerMiddleware)
    )
  );
}
```

//index component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import configureStore from './redux/store/configureStore'


const history = createHistory(); 
const store = configureStore(); 
console.log(store.getState())

const app =(
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <Router history={history}>
            <App/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

//connecting with component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import {getClientData} from './../../redux/actions/feachclientData/requestData'
import './css/user.css'


class UserInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getClientData(); 

  }
  render() {
    if(this.props.userData === 0) return null; 
    return (
      <Grid container space={8} justify='center'> 

      </Grid> 
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
   userData: state.clientData|| []
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getClientData: () => dispatch(getClientData())
  };
};
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserInfo))
```

[image]

Comment: You're initializing your store with an empty object - `const clientReducer =(state = {}, action) => { ...`, which is probably why you're getting an empty state. Try to access data from your store in one of the component lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount` - like from your `UserInfo` component

Comment: Do you mean calling  configureStore() inisde componentDidMount?

Comment: Nope, `configureStore()` should only be called once, in the `index.js` file, right where you have it.

Comment: can you post the action creator `datafeachsuccess` ?

Comment: @Sagivb.g, i added action creator at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
console.log(store.getState())
```

Before you `fetch` the data from the server.
Try to call `getClientData` first, then on the callback log `store.getState()`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `console.log(store.getState())` you have not called the api yet, so there is no posts.
You seem to call the api only once the UserInfo component is mounted (i.e. added to the DOM of the page)

Comment: I need data there, why i need to call in other place ?